# Can I save the contents of an ObservableCollection so that the list is still intact when I restart my app?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

What I want to do is have the user add items to the list. Then when they add an item I need the list to save, so that when the user closes the app and opens it again, the list they've created is still there.

Right now, I can add items to my list, but as soon as i close the app they will be gone.

```
private static ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel> Zones = new ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel>();

    public void PopulateListView(string image, string name, string address)
    {
        if (name != "" && address != "")
        {
            Zones.Add(new ViewModels.ZoneViewModel { Image = image, Name = name, Address = address });

            Application.Current.Properties["zoneslist"] = Zones;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
       if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("zoneslist"))
       {
          // Put the contents of the "zoneslist" key into a variable as a string.
          var savedZones = Application.Current.Properties["zoneslist"] as ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel>;

           // Set the listviews' itemssource to the savedzones list.
           zonesList.ItemsSource = savedZones;
       }
    }
```

Here's the code I use right now, I thought this could work to save it  but that doesn't work.

**EDIT**: So I've tried what @Alessandro Calario suggested and after using json serialization the listview just gives me a ton of empty list items(even though i only added one). But an item is added and is saved, even when the app is closed. Progress, at least, but I'm not quite there yet. Anyone know a solution?

my code:

```
public void PopulateListView(string image, string name, string address)
{
    if (name != "" && address != "")
    {
        Zones.Add(new ViewModels.ZoneViewModel { Image = image, Name = name, Address = address });

        //Serialize to json string
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Zones);

        Application.Current.Properties["zoneslist"] = json;
    }
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("zoneslist"))
    {
        // Put the contents of the "zoneslist" key into a variable as a string.
        var savedZones = Application.Current.Properties["zoneslist"] as string; //ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel>

        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel>>(savedZones);

        // Set the listviews' itemssource to the savedzones list.
        zonesList.ItemsSource = savedZones;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using 3rd parties libraries is not a thing for your project I highly recommend you to use [Akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache). This is an Async, persistent key-value store.

Once setup is very simple to use.

//To Insert your object

```
IObservable<Unit> InsertObject<T>(string key, T value, DateTimeOffset? absoluteExpiration = null);
```

//To Get your object

```
IObservable<T> GetObject<T>(string key);
```

where `T` can be your whole list.

Of course it's a little more than this but trust me just a little. Read the full documentation and hope it fits your needs.

Comment: This seems to be the perfect option for me, but I've tried it and my app saves the list, but if I add items, close the app, re-open it and add another item it overwrites the current list and adds a single item. I think it is because it still creates a new instance of the list everytime my app is started. So the old one is still set as the itemssource for the listview when the app is started. Is there any way to work around that?

Comment: You can read the content of the caching and if there's anything available you modify the list you just read and save back.

Comment: So you mean like `var _zonesList = await BlobCache.LocalMachine.GetObject<ObservableCollection<ViewModels.ZoneViewModel>>("zones");` and then add items to zonesList and save again? Because that doesn't work. I get a NullReferenceException when I try to add anything to zonesList. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can Serialize your List of Objects to a json String and save it to Application Properties

Comment: Yes, I was looking into doing this. I'll try to do it now.

Comment: Alright, I tried this, and it saves, but a ton of empty list items are now in my listview after adding one item. I will add the code I used in the question, could you have a look?

Comment: savedZones is a string. You should deserialize to an object... Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json); you deserialization is doing nothing . And pass to your ItemsSource the object (you are passing the string...)

Answer (score 1):

The Application Properties only stores primitive types.

> Note: the Properties dictionary can only serialize primitive types for
>   storage. Attempting to store other types (such as List can
>   fail silently).
>   Source: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/

Either set it up so you are using the properties as a primitive storage, or go for another local storage mechanism such as Sqlite (a good guide here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/)

Comment: I tried setting it up using the properties as a primitive storage, but I ran into another problem. Could you have a look at my edit? I added what I have now to the question.